# Count number of clients SQL

Tags: sql, count

So I'm trying to count clients that spend more than 100 in September, and the result should be simple '2'.
Here's my code

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT KLIENT)
FROM FAKTURY
WHERE MONTH(DATA) = 9
GROUP by klient
HAVING SUM(BRUTTO)>100
```

but the output is

```
1
1
```

How do i fix that?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please provide some sample data along with your expected output? It would speed things up a lot. Consider setting up a sample schema in a fiddle, such as https://dbfiddle.uk/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use another sub-query to get the desired result -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT KLIENT)
          FROM FAKTURY
         WHERE MONTH(DATA) = 9
         GROUP BY klient
        HAVING SUM(BRUTTO)>100) X;
```

Comment: Ah I tried it befor but didn't add alias at the end, so it didn't worked for me. Anyway thanks a lot!